# Running "preamble" code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to make MATLAB run a certain chunk of code every time you try to run a script? For instance, I would like MATLAB to run

```
sprintf('Here we go...')
```

as soon as I hit the Run button and then move on to execute my script, so if my script were

```
i = 1;
i = i * i;
display(i)
```

I would get

```
ans =

Here we go...


i =

      1
```

P.S. I would appreciate it if the people with higher reputation please corrected the title of my question for it to better reflect the content.

Comment: Though it is probably possible to respond to you clicking the run button in the UI, it will likely be a horribly undocumented solution that is totally overkill. Hence try some of the given (simpler&more stable) solutions that will also work if you call a script by its name rather than with the run button.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin it is actually not that horrible.

Comment: Sia, is your comment "as soon as I hit the Run button" exactly what you mean, or did you just mean something that should be executed whenever a code runs? The answers below are split between hacking the GUI and modifying scripts. I think that's because we're not sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant whenever a code runs in general, which would include clicking the Run button. And of course I'd like to do this reversibly (quickly and easily return to default settings whenever needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as soon as I hit the Run button

I am assuming you are talking about the run button in the editor. In [R2012a](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/releases/R2012a/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-131.html#brqxeeu-136) there was a feature called "Run Configuration". A run configuration was linked to a specific script and included code to be executed prior to the script being run. There does not appear to be a global setting to be used on all function. This feature appears to have been silently removed in R2012b.

In [R2013b](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-functions-in-the-editor.html) you can chose to run a different script. Presumably you could hack the [editor](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor/) to get the current file and use the custom run script to run your preamble and then the current editor file. This seems like a lot of work for not much return ...

You could create a file called `myrun.m`

```
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
jEditor = desktop.getGroupContainer('Editor').getTopLevelAncestor;
title = jEditor.getTitle;
currentFilename = char(title.replaceFirst('Editor - ',''));
fprintf('Here we go...');
run(currentFilename);
```

and this in the editor under `run` `Run: type code to run` type `myrun`. One you do this once it will remember your preferences and you can then run you code via `myrun` with `F5`. It will remember your preferences across restarts.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this would be to have a `preamble.m` and `doThis.m`. In `preamble.m` you'd have this:

```
sprintf('Here we go...')
```

and then in `doThis.m`, you'd have

```
preamble
i = 1;
i = i * i;
display(i)
```

The only trick to making this work is to have them both on the path, or in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got what you want, but you can divide Your m file into Code Sections. For example:

```
%% Section 1
sprintf('Here we go...')

%% Section 2
i = 1;
i = i * i;
display(i)
```

The `%%` is a  section break.  Place your cursor in the relevant section, and on the Editor tab, in the Run section, click Run Section. (or press Ctrl+Enter)

[see here for more info.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html)

Comment: If you want it to be displayed each time a certain piece of code is ran, they should actually be in the same section.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this for one (or a few scripts) either add the command in the script, or make a wrapper function/shortcut.

---

If you want this for many scripts without input, you can create a generic wrapper:

Suppose you want to run things like `myFun(a,b,c)` then create a wrapper that you can call like this:

`myWrapper('myFun(a,b,c)')`

Then you can first call your display command and then use `eval` on the input of `myWrapper`. Note that this becomes cumbersome if your function call is multiline or contains quotes.

---

If these solutions can't help, you probably need to ask yourself why you are trying to do this and whether there is a better solution for the underlying problem.

Comment: Sidenote: If you just want to see the message to confirmt that you clicked properly: try typing something like `1`. If you don't see it being printed yet, Matlab is still working.